# Simple email client for Linux

Tags: linux, email, software-rec, crunchbang

I am looking for a very simple email client for Linux, [Crunchbang](http://crunchbanglinux.org) specifically.

All I want for it to do is email. No calendar, todo, etc features. I would also prefer for it to be GUI-based because all of the CLI email clients I've used have been very difficult to set up and in some cases haven't worked with my email provider (MobileMe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't find one that has *no* features. [Claws](http://www.claws-mail.org/) is among the light ones though.

Answer (score 4):

I'd have to suggest Thunderbird.  Not lean and mean perhaps, but not OVER-burdened with features you won't use.  It's simple to install and well supported.  That to me is more important than sheer size (or lack of size in this case).

Comment: Also, features like Calendar and Todo are kept separate in the [Calendar](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar) add-on.

Answer (score 2):

You may find [Anjal](http://live.gnome.org/Anjal/) a good possibility as well. From their website:

> Anjal is a lite UI built on top of Evolution and uses 95% of Evolution code for its experience. Anjal was built to suit the smaller screens and low memory devices. Particularly Netbooks and the mobile segments. It has a very interesting UI, that is TOUCHable and consumes less memory and deals efficiently on the real estate for the small screens.

I haven't tried it myself, so I'm not sure whether it excludes Evolution's extra features like calendar.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Anjal Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Even if you want GUI, **[mutt](http://www.mutt.org/)** cannot be left unmentioned.